# Do block rewards appear immediately in the miner's wallet?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-reward

This question is about how Bitcoin rewards would appear in a miner's wallet. Let's assume that two miners have solved the next block hash, and broadcast their block to the network  simultaneously...

1. On solving a block hash, does the block reward show in the miner's wallets immediately, or if there some network delay or verification process that must occur before a miner sees their block reward?
2. Since both miners have solved the next block hash simultaneously, only one of them can win. In this case the network's longest chain succeeds. Would the losing miner in this case see their wallet balance decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both miners should see their total funds increase the moment they mine a block. (Since from each of their perspectives, they're on the best chain and the other chain is extinct at that moment.) Then, when one chaintip pulls ahead, the miner that found the extinct chaintip would see their funds decrease again as the stale block gets reorganized out and they switch away from their own chaintip.

However, the *spendable* funds would not increase and decrease: coinbase transaction outputs are only spendable after maturing for 100 blocks.